# Update 'global' reactive component inside observeEvent()?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to update a reactive component inside of observeEvent(), then call it later on. But the value is not passed globally, instead it is local inside observeEvent().

This does not update myText().

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name", "Enter your name:"),
  actionButton("myButton", "Click me!"),
  h4("Output:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("myOutput")
 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myText <- reactive({
    paste("Hello, ", input$name, "!")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$myButton, {
    # Update the reactive value
    myText <- reactive({
      paste("Goodbye, ")
    })
  })
  
  output$myOutput <- renderPrint({
    myText()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I renderPrint() inside observeEvent(), that works, but that is not what I want.

Is there a way to update the reactive component such that it is available globally to other function inside server()?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with `reactiveValues()`:

```
  btn1_output <- reactiveValues(value = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$myButton, {
    # Collect the reactive value
    btn1_output$value <- paste('Goodbye, ', input$name)
  })

  output$myOutput2 <- renderPrint({
    btn1_output$value
  })
```